# How to properly "refresh" a winforms ListView in virtual mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using a ListView class in virtual mode, such that the RetrieveVirtualItem event pulls the item from an independent data structure. When I want to do a major edit of the list items, I do:

```
listView.BeginUpdate();
try {
    [code to reset backing data structure]
    listView.VirtualListSize = backingDataStructure.Count;
}
finally {
    listView.EndUpdate();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to properly refresh this UI (sometimes new entries added to the backing store don't show up). What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: No, EndUpdate() should always be enough to get the ListView repainted and thus the RetrieveVirtualItem event to trigger again.  Do look for a bug in your data structure code.  You could arbitrarily set VirtualListSize to 0 first.

Comment: @HansPassant you were correct, it was a bug in my backing collection management. Thanks for putting me back on the right track! I you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled into this aging question because I have the same problem and BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() simply don't work. Failure to find a working solution in the internet, I've found a what-if solution that works (at least in my case).

Set the listview's VirtualListSize property to 0 and back on the actual number of items you want the control to show. Ex.

```
ListView.VirtualListSize = 0;
ListView.VirtualListSize = 12345;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already using the correct pattern, so the issue is likely in a different part of your code. But, for posterity, I am reiterating that pattern here. Quoting [Hans Passant’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202759/how-to-properly-refresh-a-winforms-listview-in-virtual-mode#comment33707263_22202759):

> `EndUpdate()` should always be enough to get the `ListView` repainted and thus the `RetrieveVirtualItem` event to trigger again.

Ensure you call [`BeginUpdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_BeginUpdate) before switching your virtual backing to the new data and [`EndUpdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate?view=netframework-4.7.1) after you are done. `EndUpdate()` alone will not do anything. Use this pattern:

```
listView.BeginUpdate();
currentBacking = newBacking;
listView.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use either method alone. I believe what Hans was trying to state is that the *actual* updating happens when EndUpdate() is called.

Comment: @Midas Yeah, the question already has the correct pattern. I think I ended up at this question while looking for this pattern and having an answer at all is helpful if that happens x.x. I am updating my answer so it is less confusing.